# How can i find the first index of date and time in string

Tags: javascript

I have this string with YYYY-MM-DD date format.

```
var x = "I will need 2 pieces of that product 2020-01-16 04:38:09.After that i will need another 2020-01-16 04:38:09.";
```

I need to substring the text from 0 until the beginning of the first date so the output from this whole string should be:

```
I will need 2 pieces of that product
```

Honestly because i dont know reg ex i didn't try anything.That is the reason i needed help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Show us your code please

Comment: Use regex to find the position of first occurrence of a date then substring from 0 till there and use the strip function remove any unnecessary spaces.

Comment: You can use the following regex: /.*?(?=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/

Comment: @AndrewL64 honestly because i dont know reg ex i didn't try anything.That is the reason i needed help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a regex and group for that.
You can take note here that i've used a lazy operator ( `*?` ) This way, it will only match the first part of the string, to the first date.

```
^(.*?)(?:\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})
```

This regex will match anything until it sees the date format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`. 
The first group of the match will be what you are looking for.

in Javascript, you can implement it like so :

```js
let text = 'I will need 2 pieces of that product by 2020-11-26 2020-01-16 04:38:09.After that i will need another 2020-01-16 04:38:09.';
// notice here that we are using a non-capture group around the date
// because we do not need this part.
let regex = /^(.*?)(?:\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})/;
let match = regex.exec(text);
// the first element of the array contains the whole matches,
// the second contains the first group.
console.log(match[1]);
```

Comment: What about time part?

Comment: @MaksimTikhonov it is not needed in this case since OP want only the first part of the string.

Comment: @Andrej You are very welcome, I suggest you look into the regex i provided to try and understand it, This is the key to, one day, making your own. You can check [here](https://regex101.com/r/l4LgjI/1)  for an explanation on it.

Comment: @Nicolas Yes you are right.That is my weak think in the programming.I will check and learn the explanation and thank you for your time :)

Comment: @Nicolas btw maybe i will have a problem if the user input comment is in the date format 2020-01-16 like we search in the regex.Then it will not work.How can i have regex with the time too ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you?

```js
var x = "I will need 2 pieces of that product 2020-01-16 04:38:09.After that i will need another 2020-01-16 04:38:09.";

var year = (new Date()).getFullYear();

var result = x.substr(0, x.indexOf(year));

alert(result);
```

Comment: What if the date is yesterday, last year or 34000 years from now ?

Comment: Then use RegExp to detect any date index

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:
it matches everything until (4 numbers) followed by (-) followed by (2 numbers) followed by (-) followed by (2 numbers) appear.

```js
const regex = /(.*?)\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/;
const str = `I will need 2 pieces of that product 2020-01-16 04:38:09.After that i will need another 2020-01-16 04:38:09.`;
let m;

if ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    console.log(m[1]);
}
```

output will be

> I will need 2 pieces of that product